# Use if-else function on data frame with multiple values

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data frame that contains multiple values in each spot, like this:

```
ID<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,6)
W<-c(29,72,32,33,34,44,42,78,32,42,18,26,10,34,39)
df1<-data.frame(ID, W)
df<-ddply(df1, .(ID), summarize,
                  X=paste(unique(W),collapse=","))

  ID           X
1  1    29,72,32
2  2 33,34,44,42
3  3       78,32
4  4    42,18,26
5  5          10
6  6       34,39
```

I am trying to generate another column using an if-else function so that every ID that has an X value greater than 70 will show a 1, and all others will show a 0, like this:

```
  ID           X Y
1  1    29,72,32 1
2  2 33,34,44,42 0
3  3       78,32 1
4  4    42,18,26 0
5  5          10 0
6  6       34,39 0
```

This is the code that I tried:

```
df$Y <- ifelse(df$X>=70, 1, 0)
```

But it doesn't work; it only seems to put the first value of each spot through the function:

```
  ID           X Y
1  1    29,72,32 0
2  2 33,34,44,42 0
3  3       78,32 1
4  4    42,18,26 0
5  5          10 0
6  6       34,39 0
```

It worked fine on my one column that has only one value per spot. Is there a way to get to the if-else function to evaluate every value in each spot and assign a 1 if any of them fit the statement?

Thank you, I'm sorry that I do not know a lot of R vocabulary yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As 'X' is a string, we can split the 'X' at the `,` to create a `list` of `vector`s, loop over the `list` with `map` check if there are `any` `numeric` converted values are greater than 70

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)    
df %>%
      mutate(Y = map_int(strsplit(X, ","), ~ +(any(as.numeric(.x) > 70))))
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! You are amazing!!